# Responsive joomla site doesnt work in browser, but on mobile devices

Tags: css, browser, responsive

My joomla site http://fm-coding.de doesn´t act responsive in browsers, if I resize them nothing changes, at least not what I want to resize. Mainly it´s about the tables, on this site for example: [http://fm-coding.de/codierungen/bmw/1er/e81-e82-e87-e88](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfX7M.jpg) They should look good on all devices, I could test iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 and got it looking good there, but if I test it with a browser, I don´t see any changes.

For example for an iPhone 6:

```
    @media only screen 
     and (min-width: 375px) 
     and (max-width: 667px) 
     and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
     and (orientation: portrait) { 
    .div-table-col{width:315px}
    .sppb-tab{width:340px}
    .fb-page{
        width    : 350px;
        height   : 350px;
        margin-left : -175px;
        margin-top  : -175px;}
}
```

I´ve also added the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in my templates index.php

Am I missing something? Without a responsive design that´s not working in browser its very hard to see, if it works on every phone or tablet.

For me it look like this, first how it look in my browser and the other two how it´s suppose to look:

[Browser view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfX7M.jpg)

[Browser view 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr2Ia.jpg)

[Mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj5Jv.png)

[Mobile view 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBist.png)

Comment: please format code properly.

Comment: for me everything is responsive, even on my chrome browser

Comment: What do you mean "format code proberly" Because only above "}" was missing? Check the picture in my edited post.